# MySql and SQL Server resources utilization comparision

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, iis, sql

Does Apache with MySql will use less system resources (RAM, CPU utilization) if we develop a web application instead of IIS with Sql Server?

My friend told that MYSQL consume very less when compared to SQL Server.

I have both PHP and ASP.NET skills. Which one will be preferable to develop application?

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that MySQL has more flexibility, it can use just a few resources or lot of them just changing configuration parameters. Same with Apache. You can have a MySQL Apache stack running in a 512MB RAM server or 48GB RAM server using the resources efficiently.

In the other hand, SQL Server + IIS stack has a biggest base requirements (al least dual core + 4GB RAM).

Also an Apache-MySQL stack has the following benefits:

- No licences needed (Windows, IIS and SQL Server)
- Easy to find a hosting to support it
- Hosting is cheaper for LAMP stack
- Apache-MySQL is multiplatform

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Both will use as much or as little RAM as you care to give them. With MySQL, however, you have to do a lot more tuning by hand (key cache size, query cache size, sort buffer size, InnoDB buffer pool size, etc.)

With SQL server, set "Maximum Server RAM", and if you're on a 32-bit system having virtual address space issues, the "Mem To Leave" startup option as well. That's about it.

Also, I find that MySQL does a somewhat ungraceful job of handling thread scheduling, and running unexpectedly intensive queries can easily make the server nearly unresponsive. I almost never have that issue with SQL Server (save for keeping a transaction running too long and causing massive lock contention, but that isn't a performance/scheduling issue).

I work with both platforms very frequently, and that's what I've observed.